# How to validate Apple's "Auto-Renewable In App Purchase Receipt Validation" API using java?

Tags: java, ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, in-app-purchase-receipt

Can someone guide me how to test iOS(auto-renewable IAP) Receipt Validation API by using Sandbox URL?

I have tried this below snippet.

```
public void validateReceiptData(VerifyReceiptRequestView requestview) {
        System.out.println("validateReceiptData ....................");
        String VERIFICATION_URL=" https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(VERIFICATION_URL);
            JSONObject requestData = new JSONObject();
            requestData.put("receipt-data", requestview.getReceiptdata());
            requestData.put("password", requestview.getPassword());
            StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(requestData.toString());
            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.setEntity(requestEntity);
            HttpResponse response =httpClient.execute(request);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            System.out.println("responseJSON -------------->"+responseJSON);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But I need sample request data for the below mentioned fields

```
requestData.put("receipt-data", requestview.getReceiptdata());
requestData.put("password", requestview.getPassword());
```

Does the field `requestview.getReceiptdata()` requires any Valid Purchased receipt or does Apple provides any sample receipt data to test this API in SandBox environment.

Comment: Yes, receipt-data requires the receipt to be a valid receipt. As far as I know, you would have to get it from an iOS device.